# Office-ui-fabric React JS Dropdown Select Index

Tags: reactjs, selection, dropdown, office-ui-fabric

I'm using Office-ui-fabric in React-JS. I'm working on a Dropdown, and the values inside the dropdown change. My problem is that I cannot control the Selected Index manually. Every time the values change the last selected index is addressed. 
i.e.: 
Dog
Cat
**Horse** (selected)
I change the array:
Dog
Cat
Now there is no selection whatsoever because it tries to address the 3rd row.

I searched for some answers but all I got is to change the 'selected' value of the row from FALSE to TRUE. But I don't have one, and if I add it, it still doesn't work

```
import {Dropdown} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown'
<Dropdown options={optionsArray} onChanged={(val)=> onChangeProperty(id, val.key)}>
```

My optionsArray is:

```
cosnt optionsArray =[
{key: '1', text: "Cat"},
{key: '2', text: "Dog"},
{key: '3', text: "Horse"},
]
```

Comment: Do you have the code for onChangeProperty? Have you tried these? https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/tree/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Dropdown/examples

Comment: I would look at the basic example and usage of `selectedKey` property for the Dropdown component

Comment: I have looked into both selectedKey and onChangeProperty, and I have found a workaround. I have wrapped the Dropdown element by my own. And add a boolean and a key value to pass, that determines whether i should Override the currently selected value or use the passed one. I do not consider this a real solution, but rather a workaround. I have looked into the Dropdown Element from Fabric, and found there is a private function that simply receives an index and puts the Dropdown value into the selectedKey attribute. Too bad it's private

Answer (score 0):

use selectedKey to select the vale in Dropdown. To do that you need to declare useState as below:

```
const [option, setOption] = useState('');
```

Then you need to set the value using setOption like

```
setOption('2'); // 2 is the key for Dog in your example
```

finally in UI, you need to use selectedKey props

```
<Dropdown selectedKey={option} options={optionsArray} onChanged={(val)=> onChangeProperty(id, val.key)}>
```